# New to Java -- Return Unit test failing

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, string-length

Im working on a Java program in class and im unsure why or how this is failing considering I get the correct print out when the program is ran.

Here is the code I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAnalyzer {

    // Create scanner

    private static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Create text string
    private static String text;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
        // Scan for text input
        text = scnr.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + text);

        // Call getNumOfCharacters
        int count = getNumOfCharacters();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + count);
        // Call outputWithoutWhitespace
        String modifiedstring = outputWithoutWhitespace();
        System.out.println("String with no whitespace: " + modifiedstring);

    }

    // Method outputs string without spaces

    private static String outputWithoutWhitespace() {
        text = text.trim().replaceAll(" ", "");
        return text;
    }

    // Method to return number of characters

    private static int getNumOfCharacters() {
        return text.length();
    }
}
```

The output passes on all levels, it's the Unit test for the number of characters in the input that is failing and I really just need some guidance as a new student to Java programming.

Here is a printout of the tests:

[image]

My assumption is that the `getNumOfCharacters()` is returning the number of characters AFTER the whitespaces have been removed, but I could be wrong.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: avoid linking to external site for more information. And: only post relevant code. Meaning: instead of pasting your main method here, you would better post the source code of the failing unit test instead. In other words: please turn to the help center and read "how to ask".

Comment: Is your method name wrong? Tests say **GetNumOfCharacters** (capital G)

Comment: @GhostCat New users can't inline images until they have 10 rep. You can and should help them out by editing. There is enough info here to look at the issue, and the program itself is minimal enough to comprehend at a glance. This is a pretty clear question with precisely all of the information we always ask people for.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct and the problem is that you are replacing `text` with the *stripped* `text`:

```
private static String outputWithoutWhitespace() {
    text = text.trim().replaceAll(" ", "");
    return text;
}
```

... and now `getNumOfCharacters()` is returning the *stripped* length, which is no longer e.g. 46.

That is, when you hit this line in `main`:

```
String modifiedstring = outputWithoutWhitespace();
```

It has the side-effect of replacing `text`, since that's precisely what you told `outputWithoutWhitespace()` to do. So by the time `main` ends, `text` now contains the modified text, and subsequent calls to `getNumOfCharacters()` fail the unit tests.

Your printed output is misleading (still prints "46") because you compute and store the character count *before* you mess up `text` in `outputWithoutWhitespace()`.

This is a good exercise in how to process and manage data, and a good learning experience for you. It's also a nice demonstration of the value of unit tests in quality control; you should remember this lesson.

Here's a hint: Based on your application requirements, does `outputWithoutWhitespace()` *really* need to *store* the trimmed text? Or does it just need to return it?

In the future, for debugging, consider:

- Stepping through in a debugger where possible to examine what's happening along the way.
- Adding diagnostic printouts, for example, print the value of `text` in `getNumOfCharacters()` to verify that it is what you think it is. Especially given your assumption that the problem was here and the failed unit test, this would be a good place to start investigating.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think it might be a combo of what Jason C and @cricket_007 said. I stripped it down and tried to force test just the GetNumOfCharacters() and was still unable to pass the test. Im going to give it a rest and move on for now but I will stop back here if I figure out the solution!

Thank you for your help!